# SimpMessagingTemplate vs MessageSendingOperations

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I've just started to study Spring 4 stomp over websocket. What are the differences between these two? What cases should I use one over the another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference: `MessageSendingOperations` is an interface - contract.
`SimpMessagingTemplate` is a concrete implementation of the first one.

Typically it's enough to configure bean for concrete implementation, but inject it by type of its conctract:

```
@Bean
public MessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate() {
    return new SimpMessagingTemplate(this.inputChannel);
}

...

@Component
public class MyService {

   @Autowired
   private MessageSendingOperations  messagingTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that `SimpMessagingTemplate` class implements the contracts specified in the `MessageSendingOperations` interface, you will in practice use `SimpMessagingTemplate` when you want to send a message to a specific user.

This is because (at the time of writing), the `SimpMessageTemplate` also implements the subinterface `SimpMessageSendingOperations` that offers the `convertAndSendToUser` body of methods.