# Spring Websocket MessageSendingOperation not working without @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

```
.
.
.
@Autowired
private MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate;


@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void sendMessage(){

           messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/data","hello"); 

    }
}
```

The above works. but

```
sendMessage();

public void sendMessage(){

           messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/data", "hello");

    }
}
```

doesn't work, it got java.lang.NullPointerException

Does that mean I could only use  messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(...) inside a function annotated with @Scheduled?

Please help...
@Deendayal Garg, thanks for your help, I did this this according to your advice:
    public class Communicator implements ApplicationListener {

```
private final MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate;

@Autowired
public Communicator(final MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate){
    this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
}

public void onApplicationEvent(BrokerAvailabilityEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


public void sendMessage(Message data) {
    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/data",data.getBody());
    System.out.println(new Random().nextInt(100));
  }
}
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
    final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}


@Bean
public Communicator communicator(){
    Communicator comm = new Communicator();
    return comm;
}
```

}

Then I injected the bean in the class below

```
public class StepExecListener implements StepExecutionListener, ApplicationListener<BrokerAvailabilityEvent>{
@Autowired
Communicator communicator;
Message msg = new Message();
msg.setBody("Twale!");
msg.setType("test");

communicator.sendDataUpdates(msg);
}
```

But I still got it got java.lang.NullPointerException after calling communicator.sendDataUpdates(msg);

Comment: Is your class which contains `sendMessage` is a bean? if not then make it a bean then inject that bean wherever you want `sendMessage` function to be called...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have edited the question, kindly see the updated version above.

Comment: How is your spring configuration done? I feel somehow the `MessageSendingOperations` bean is not getting autowired properly. Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856400/simpmessagingtemplate-vs-messagesendingoperations